# Empty array shows null data at o index php

Tags: php, arrays

I had created a function which returns an array

```
<?php function get_subset($s , $e){
       $subset = array(); 
       return $subset;
      }
```

on displayin subset

```
<pre><?php echo $subset; ?></pre>
```

output is

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I want the array to return null .

Comment: So, you wanted `$array[0]` to be `$array[0] => NULL` ?

Comment: Exactly i want it to be NULL

Comment: `$subset = array(null);`  should work.

Comment: but on foreach loop , if loop runs 8 time and storing data in $subset = $products, after echo $subset, the array has 9 index in which 0 index shows data as in my question and rest 1 to 9 has the data i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_subset($a, $b)
{
    $subset = array();
    return $subset;
}
$subset = get_subset(null,null); 
var_dump( $subset==null);
```

its already returning null,
you need to get the return value. you cannt access variable defined inside a function outside.
Both $subset are in different scope.